# Looping in SQL while creating a view

Tags: sql, loops

Im having a hard time looping using sql, the table Im using `resources` references itself by having a `parent` column so I want to do the following logic while creating the view in sql but I'm stuck...

```
since im using a left join between my auth_permissions table and resource table, we are always looking at a row of type 'table'

- for the current row in table resources which is always of type 'table'

- give me the rows parent which is in position resources[4] 

- then go to the row where id is equal to resources[4] which is of type 'schema'. spit out the 'name' column 
- then go to that rows parent which is of type 'database' and spit out the 'name' column
```

> What my current sql query looks like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW dev.permissions
AS select
    left(rls.name, length(rls.name) - 5) AS "users",
    res.name    as "table",
    ap.p_create as "insert",
    ap.p_read   as "select",
    ap.p_update as "update",
    ap.p_delete as "delete"
   FROM dev.auth_permissions ap
     LEFT JOIN dev.roles rls ON rls.id = ap.role_id
     LEFT JOIN dev.resources res ON res.id = ap.resource_id
```

The result of my SQL query

```
users      table      insert   select   update   delete

student    midterm    false    true      false    false
student    midterm    false    true      false    false

teacher    midterm    true     true      true     true
teacher    midterm    false    true      true     true

sub        midterm    false    true      false    false
sub        midterm    false    true      false    false
```

This is what I want my view to look like / the final SQL query result

```
users       database             schema        table      insert   select   update   delete

student     PrivateDatabase      English       midterm    false    true      false    false
student     PrivateDatabase      Math          midterm    false    true      false    false

teacher     PrivateDatabase      English       midterm    true     true      true     true
teacher     PrivateDatabase      Math          midterm    false    true      true     true

sub         PrivateDatabase      English       midterm    false    true      false    false
sub         PrivateDatabase      Math          midterm    false    true      false    false
```

The tables im using to create the view look like so

> **roles Table**

```
 id   code     name     description  

 1     245     student    null   
 2     411     teacher    null  
 3     689      sub       null
```

> **resources Table**, the parent column references itself so that I can track the parent of a table or schema. But a database has no parent since its at the top of the hierarchy

```
 id         origin         type         name           parent

 1     PrivateDatabase     database    summer2020      null
 2     PrivateDatabase     schema      English         1
 3     PrivateDatabase     table       midterm         2
 4     PrivateDatabase     schema      Math            1
 5     PrivateDatabase     table       midterm         4
```

> **auth_permissions Table**, role_id reference the `roles` table and resources reference the `resources` table

```
 id    role_id   resource_id    p_create   p_read   p_update    p_delete

 1      1         3             false      true     false       false
 2      1         5             false      true     false       false


 3      2         3             true       true     true        true
 4      2         5             true       true     true        true


 5      3         3             false      true     false       false
 6      3         5             false      true     false       false
```

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE! Any feedback is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the `resources` table twice more in your query to fetch the schema and database names. In each case you join the `id` to the previous instantiations `parent` value:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW permissions AS
SELECT
    rls.name AS "users",
    res3.name    as "database",
    res2.name    as "schema",
    res.name    as "table",
    ap.p_create as "insert",
    ap.p_read   as "select",
    ap.p_update as "update",
    ap.p_delete as "delete"
FROM auth_permissions ap
LEFT JOIN roles rls ON rls.id = ap.role_id
LEFT JOIN resources res ON res.id = ap.resource_id 
LEFT JOIN resources res2 ON res2.id = res.parent
LEFT JOIN resources res3 ON res3.id = res2.parent
```

Sample query:

```
SELECT *
FROM permissions
```

Output (for your sample data)

```
users       database    schema      table       insert  select  update  delete
student     summer2020  English     midterm     false   true    false   false
student     summer2020  Math        midterm     false   true    false   false
teacher     summer2020  Math        midterm     true    true    true    true
teacher     summer2020  English     midterm     true    true    true    true
sub         summer2020  Math        midterm     false   true    false   false
sub         summer2020  English     midterm     false   true    false   false
```

Note I've assumed you want the database `name`, not its `origin`. If you really want the `origin` value, just change `res3.name` in the query to `res3.origin`.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah my mistake it was the database I was looking for.